# In which order should I read these topics?

Tags: reference-request

In which order should these topic be read if one have to understand mathematics topic well?

Differential Equations

Game Theory

Graph Theory

Linear Programming

Probability

Statistics

Vector Analysis

Algebraic Geometry

Analytic Geometry

Differential Geometry

Mathematical Analysis

Matrices

Calculus

Combinatorics

Fractals

Set Theory

Many of you would like to know why you wanna read all these topics, the answer is I wish to be a game programmer and I know it is not mandatory to know these topic but for having a deeper understanding I wish to study them so without further ado I would like to know from where should I start?

Thank You

Comment: That's a long list of topics, and covering all of them (even at an introductory level) takes a lot of time. I would suggest starting with set theory, matrices and calculus, and then seeing if you want to continue.

Comment: What is your current level of education? That is almost an entire undergraduate mathematics majors curriculum.

Comment: I have voted to close as this question is too broad and primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

> "I wish to be a game programmer"

Then your list does not (in my opinion) encompass the ideal topics.
I would include:

- Calculus
- Analytic Geometry
- Linear Algebra (emphasizing geometric interpretations)
- Physics (mechanics)
- Quaternions
- Discrete Math; Graph Theory
- Probability & Statistics
- Computational Geometry